# Save and load highcharter graph in R

Tags: r, highcharts, r-highcharter

I would like to be able to **save** and then **load** my highcharts graphs created with **highcharter** in **R**.

I have tried using the `save` function in R.

- When I load the RDA object into R it just gives me the name of the object as a string rather than the object it self.
- I used `save(graph1, file="new_graph.rda")` then
  `x=load("new_graph.rda")`, the object x is a character string called
  with the value `graph1`.

I have also tried to use the `htmlwidgets::saveWidget(graph1, file="html_graph.html")`, and then pull it back in using `graph2 = htmltools::includeHTML("html_graph.html")` but this just gives me the text html and doesnt render the graph.

I tried to render it using `htmlwidgets::createWidget("widget", graph2)`, but I just get a blank screen.

**How can I save and then load in highcharts graphs?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `x=load("new_graph.rda")` try `load("new_graph.rda")`.

Cheers, Rico